# Creating HTML report from SQlite3 database in Python

Tags: python, html, sqlite

I am currently using the code below to select certain information from an Sqlite3 database to give information back to the user. I am wondering if somebody could point me in the right direction to a library/function that can allow me to create an easy to read HTML report for the user rather than the standard terminal shown?

Kind regards.

```
connect = sqlite3.connect(sqlitedb)
with connect:
    cur = connect.cursor()
    cur.execute("""SELECT messages._id,messages.body, participants_info.number, participants_info.display_name, participants_info._id
        FROM messages
        INNER JOIN participants_info
        ON messages.participant_id = participants_info._id;""")
while True:

row = cur.fetchone()
if row == None:
    break
print (row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've never used it myself but, i know that `pandas` has a DataFrame.to_html method so what you can do is:
`import pandas as pd
frame = pd.read_sql_query(your_query, sql_connection)
frame.to_html()`
you can read [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) for specifics